# "nanopb" (protobuf c) it can be used on android?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

this is nanopb website https://code.google.com/p/nanopb/

i dont know nanopb it can be used on android and iOS?

thanks

Best Wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C language code in android and iOS. In android NDK is provided for native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

However, if your main application is in Java, it is probably not very pleasant to use a Protocol Buffers library through NDK. It will require a lot of boilerplate code in marshalling the messages back and forth.

I would suggest using the Google's own Java protobuf library, in its "nano" configuration mode.